# np.tile to repeat an 1D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an ndarray, `A`, 
and I want to multiply this ndarray element wise by another 1D array `b` where I assume that `A.shape[i] = len(b)` for some `i`. I need this generality in my application.

I can do this using `np.tile` as follows:

```
A = np.random.rand(2,3,5,9)
b = np.random.rand(5)
i = 2
b_shape = np.ones(len(A.shape), dtype=np.int)
b_shape[i] = len(b)
b_reps = list(A.shape)
b_reps[i] = 1
B = np.tile(b.reshape(b_shape), b_reps)

# Here B.shape = A.shape and
# B[i,j,:,k] = b for all i,j,k
```

This strikes me as ugly. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Probbaly `A*b[:,None]`. For more info read up on `NumPy broadcasting`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular example, the following code would do the trick:

```
result = A*b[:, np.newaxis]
```

For any value of `i`, try this:

```
A2, B = np.broadcast_arrays(A, b)
result = A2*B
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks like what I need. @Divakar is even more compact.